# Making a GET with a FORM - how to set querystring parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller method like this:

```
    public ActionResult Create(string project_title)
    {
        return View(new ProjectViewModel()
        {
            Title = project_title
        });
    }
```

On another page, I want to take the value of a textbox, and send as a querystring parameter to this method.

My view on this page looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Project", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="text" id="project_title" name="project_title" placeholder="Title of your project" class="input-lg" />
    <input type="submit" value="Get started" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
}
```

However, while I thought that would work, I get the following error:

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the error message you are getting has nothing to do with the code you have shown in your question. Probably the `ProjectController` class in which this `Create` action is defined has some non-default constructor for which you haven't properly configured your DI framework to inject the correct dependency:

```
public class ProjectController : Controller
{
    public ProjectController(IFoo foo)
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Create(string project_title)
    {
        return View(new ProjectViewModel()
        {
            Title = project_title
        });
    }
}
```

If you don't have a default (parameterless) parameterless constructor of your controller ASP.NET MVC default's controller factory won't be able to instantiate this `ProjectController` unless you are using some DI framework and specify the concrete type to be injected in this constructor.

Comment: You are correct. I am starting to setup my windsor framework and forgot to hook it up - duh! You just saved me for a long time debugging this code... (note to self: goto bed sometimes). THANKS!